# What can I say about expected value of expected value of x given y: $E[E[X|Y]]$

Tags: probability, means, expected-value

My question is about Y that is discrete and for some random variable X, but if its having a meaning for Y that is continuous then please give that case your attention.

What can I say about $E[E[X|Y]]$?

I know that E[X|Y] is random variable, so It's not trivial case when we calculate expected value of just a number.

And what about $E[E[X|Y]|Y]$? does something like this have a meaning?
if it's, then does for some function $g$ (for simplicity, assuming g with suitable range and continuous) it's true to say that:
$$E[g(Y)E[X|Y]|Y]=g(Y)E[E[X|Y]|Y]$$
Because of a theorem that I seen:
$$E[g(Y)X|Y]=g(Y)E[X|Y]$$

Comment: In $E[E[X\mid Y]]$ the inner expectation is over $X$ given $Y$ and is a function of $Y$, while the outer expectation is over $Y$ and is a numerical value.  So to the extent that $E[E[X\mid Y] \mid Y]$ has a meaning, it is the same thing

Comment: @Henry 
$E[E[X∣Y]∣Y] $ is the same as $E[E[X∣Y]]$? or that you meant that the interpretation of this follows as it was with $E[E[X∣Y]]$?

Comment: If you define $g(y)=E[X \mid Y=y]$ then $E[X \mid Y] = g(Y)$ and $E[E[X \mid Y]] = E[g(Y)]=E[X]$.  You can also say  that conditioned on $Y=y$ you have $g(Y)=g(y)$ and thus in general and rather obviously $g(Y)=g(Y)$, so in that sense $E[E[X \mid Y]\mid Y]$ ought to mean $E[g(Y) \mid Y] = E[g(Y)]$ and we already know that is $E[X]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is measurable wrt $\sigma(Y)$ i.e. the $\sigma$-algebra generated by random variable $Y$ then $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]=X$.

This can be applied on $Z:=\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ because $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ is by definition measurable wrt $\sigma(Y)$.

This results in $\mathbb E[Z\mid Y]=Z$ or equivalently: $$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid Y]\mid Y]=\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$$

Answer (score 2):

It is  a basic fact about conditional expectations that $E(E(X|Y))=EX$.